# Zend Framework 2, authenticate

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I need help. I have this code to authenticate the user, the error is in the `init` function that is not performing the function `mvcPreDispatch`. Thanks!

```
public function init(ModuleManager $moduleManager)
{
    $sharedEvents = $moduleManager->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
    $sharedEvents->attach('zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController',
            MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'mvcPreDispatch'), 100);
}

public function mvcPreDispatch($e)
{   
    $auth = new AuthenticationService;
    $auth->setStorage(new SessionStorage("Admin"));

    $controller = $e->getTarget();
    $matchedRoute = $controller->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName();

    if (!$auth->hasIdentity() and ($matchedRoute === 'admin' OR $matchedRoute === 'admin/paginator'))
    {
        return $controller->redirect()->toRoute("auth");
    }

}
```

Comment: When I access the admin route without authentication, mvcPreDispatch function should be performed to protect the route, but it does not .Don't I know why, I am beginner in ZF2.

Comment: what happens exactly? explain in detail...show your efforts

Comment: When I access the admin route without being authenticated, the init function that is in module.config must perform the function mvcPreDispatch but this is not happening .Thus my admin route is unprotected. This part of the code is not running when it should be.

Comment: $sharedEvents->attach('zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController',
                MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'mvcPreDispatch'), 100);

Comment: Thank you for your attention but I have found the error and fixed it. It was only a matter of case sensitive in the way used in init.

Comment: case letter are same .....what is exact error?

Comment: @MarkusKoyner, happy to know that you have found the error and fixed it. Can you also mention it here as what exactly did you find and how you solved it. It might help someone in future.

Comment: The event identifier - `zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController` Should be **`Z`**`end\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController` (Capital 'Z' in Zend)